# How to convert string to JSON obj?

Tags: go

Below is the code that I've tried but to no avail:

```
    jsonObj, err := json.Marshal(supportJSONString)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s", jsonObj)
```

Comment: That string _is_ a JSON object. Do you mean that you want to convert it to a Go struct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its already a json object.
All you need to do is

```
jsonObj := []byte(supportJsonString)
```

You can then return it as HTTP response.
But in the most generic case, you would want to create a struct as response object and the marshal it to json instead of using strings this way.

Comment: thats doens't make json object, it still string

Comment: thats the binary json string which the OP wants to return as response to HTTP request.

Comment: there is no such thing like _the binary json string_. Your code is just an array of bytes.

Comment: @Зелёный: JSON objects *are* strings. All JSON is represented as a string. If it's not a string, it's not JSON.

Comment: @rockstar JSON is a text format for data interchange..in case you want to understand better, try marshalling, say a struct to JSON and then print the stringified object..you will see the format similiar to your supportJsonString.

Comment: @Shank: All JSON is serialized. "Serialized JSON" would be a redundancy.